# Cannot assign "''": "IncomeExpense.username" must be a "User" instance

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am working on this below code, trying the add data to the table by getting the values from the form. I have also marked where I am getting the error with `#`.

I have pasted `views.py`, `models.py` and `createentry.html` below. What might be the reason why I am getting this error and also explain me what I can change to get rid of this error.

```py
#views.py

def create_entry_form(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        entry_type=request.POST.get("expensetype")
        amount=request.POST.get("amount")
        details=request.POST.get("entrydetails")
        capture_date=time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        entry_username=request.POST.get("entryusername")

        entry=IncomeExpense.objects.create(entry_type=entry_type, amount=amount, details=details, capture_date=capture_date, username=entry_username) #getting_error_in_this_line
        entry.save()
        user_balance = UserBalance.objects.filter(username=username).values_list('balance', flat=True)[0]
        if entry_type=="income":
            total_balance = user_balance + amount
        else:
            total_balance=user_balance - amount


        update_balance=UserBalance.objects.get(username=username)
        update_balance.value=total_balance
        update_balance.save()
        return render(request, "homepage.html", {'name':username, 'balance':total_balance})

    else:
        return redirect("www.google.com")
```

```html
<!---- createentry.html ---->
<form action="{% url 'create_entry_form' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
<div class="container register-form">
            <div class="form">
                <div class="note">
                    <p>Create Entry Form</p>
                </div>

                <div class="form-content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select name="expensetype" id="expensetype" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="expensetype">Select Expense Type</option>
                                    <option value="income">income</option>
                                    <option value="expense">expense</option>

                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the Amount" value=""/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="entrydetails" id="entrydetails" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the entry details" value=""/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="entryusername" id="entryusername" class="form-control" placeholder="{{name}}" value=""/>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

```py
#models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class IncomeExpense(models.Model):
    entry_type=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    amount=models.IntegerField()
    details=models.TextField()
    capture_date=models.DateField()
    username=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}"


class UserBalance(models.Model):
    balance=models.IntegerField()
    username=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Also, why am I getting an error `Cannot assign "''": "IncomeExpense.username" must be a "User" instance.` and if I change something I get another similar one.

I tried changing the username to `username__username` inside this method:

```py
entry=IncomeExpense.objects.create(entry_type=entry_type, amount=amount, details=details, capture_date=capture_date, username=entry_username)
```

Comment: Are you create current user ```IncomeExpense``` ??

Comment: yes i have done it

Comment: what may be the error?

Comment: Some broken English was fixed. Many obsolete "thanks in advance"-style phrases were removed. Syntax highlighting and inline code formatting was added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we use `username` field to save `user id` but you pass `username`.That is wrong.

```
def create_entry_form(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        entry_type=request.POST.get("expensetype")
        amount=request.POST.get("amount")
        details=request.POST.get("entrydetails")
        capture_date=time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        entry_username=request.POST.get("entryusername")

        entry=IncomeExpense.objects.create(entry_type=entry_type, amount=amount, details=details, capture_date=capture_date, username=request.user) #getting_error_in_this_line
        entry.save()
        user_balance = UserBalance.objects.filter(username=request.user).values_list('balance', flat=True)[0]
        if entry_type=="income":
            total_balance = user_balance + amount
        else:
            total_balance=user_balance - amount


        update_balance=UserBalance.objects.get(username=request.user)
        update_balance.balance=total_balance
        update_balance.save()
        return render(request, "homepage.html", {'name':request.user, 'balance':total_balance})

    else:
        return redirect("www.google.com")
```

Comment: Here we save current user id into `IncomeExpense` model

Comment: i am updating the values which is balance amount in to this incomeexpense table

Comment: let me try it and let you know

Comment: i am getting this error dude Cannot assign "2": "IncomeExpense.username" must be a "User" instance.

Comment: Okay. i am available now.

Comment: Please change `request.user.id` to `request.user`

Comment: bro i am getting error here in this line user_balance = UserBalance.objects.filter(username=username).values_list('balance', flat=True)[0]

Comment: name 'username' is not defined

Comment: Try This: `user_balance = UserBalance.objects.filter(username=request.user).values_list('balance', flat=True)[0]`

Comment: trying bro...let you know

Comment: is entry.save() after create necessary?

Comment: update_balance=UserBalance.objects.get(username=request.user)
        update_balance.value=total_balance
        update_balance.save()

Comment: change `get` to `filter`.like this: `update_balance=UserBalance.objects.filter(username=request.user)`

Comment: QuerySet' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: update_balance=UserBalance.objects.filter(username=request.user)
        update_balance.value=total_balance
        update_balance.save()

Comment: Please change `update_balance.value=total_balance`  to `update_balance.balance=total_balance`

You have no field named `value` in `UserBalance` model.